# Build variant with minSDK 21 gives ClassNotFoundException for class on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, dex

I recently added MultiDex in my app and I started experiencing log build times so I followed the guide from android site about [multidex](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) and I have added a prod flavor with minSDK = 21.

After switching to `devDebug` build variant and tried to run the app I get :

```
09-12 12:02:15.168 7849-7849/css.myapp.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: css.myapp.debug, PID: 7849
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/css.myapp.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/css.myapp.debug-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/css.myapp.debug-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/css.myapp.debug-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5141)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider
      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 12 more
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

Edit :

1. Adding a flavor with minSDK 16 (which is the same I use in `defaultConfig` ) or
2. Switching to previous commit 
   both makes the app running again without this problem.

Comment: Did you solve it? I have same issue. Crash on 5.1, but works ok on 6.0+

Comment: @deviant I'm not sure how I solved it. I think `MyApplication` class was wrong cause I was extending `MultiDexApplication` and also using `attachBaseContext()` method. You only need one of these. I switched back to extending `Application` class and added the code below : ` @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(MyApplication.this);
    }
`
Let me know if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the following when you **`targetSdkVersion` < API 21** [see documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-on-l).

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
```

I.e. to fix it just:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
```